# Ubuntu cron running but nothing happening in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, cron

I have set up the Cron on my Ubuntu server and it is running every 5 minutes, everything ran fine for about a week, but now the cron still runs (it appears in the logs) but according to Magento the last cron was ages ago! There are no errors in the cron logs.

I missed a few sales from eBay because of this.

Any ideas of how to get Magento run cron again or to debug it?

**EDIT:** Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499471/m2e-cron-jobs-not-automatically-running-in-magento.
Maybe it is just the M2E extension not running in the cron.

**EDIT 2:** There is no `cron.lock` file, and the `cron_shedule` table is empty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I contacted M2E support and they had a look at my server, they couldn't see anything wrong at all, so they came up with a work around.

Setting this in the crontab fixed my issue

```
wget -q http://www.yoursite.co.uk/cron.php -O /dev/null
```

Instead of using the PHP command or cron.sh

Answer (score 7):

Try using this extension (free) http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/magento-cron-scheduler.html it logs and details the Magento cron tasks & should give you a better idea of what is happening.

Comment: I seem to get a 500 error when running that :(

Comment: I had a non working magento cron. Even running the cron.php directly in the browser didn't work. Installing this plugin magically solved all problems for me.

Answer (score 3):

Run it manually and see if it gives you any errors. You can also tell cron to log the results in a file you specify:

```
*/5 * * * * user /usr/bin/php -f /path/to/your/cron/file >> /path/to/your/log/file 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try cron.sh in your crontab instead. Just ensure `chmod +x cron.sh` first.

Also sometimes the php executable can be `php5` instead of `php`.

Comment: cron.sh is what I'm using, should I try the PHP one instead?

Comment: If I understand correctly, cron.sh only calls cron.php, so running cron.php should make no difference.

Comment: It is merely a wrapper for the .php method, yes. It is intended to make finding the path to the php binary and installation path trivial for such people on shared hosting plans, who do not know the technical paths to the executable.